# Is there a way to bulk import email addresses into a Trello Account?

Tags: gmail, trello

Is there a way to bulk import email addresses into a Trello Account?

I would like to be able to set up 60 users who are all in my Gmail contact list, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Is there a way to bulk import, or do I have to individually import email addresses?

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to add several members to a board or organization, you can add all of their email addresses in the "Add Members..." dialog, using commas to separate them.

Comment: You can also build that contact list in a Gmail email, and copy the text over to Trello.

Comment: it still requires you to "click to invite" each user.

Comment: actually it sends to all when you do commas and press enter. It just doesn't look like it goes to all.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet for a big launch is to make an example board that is not private, share a link options>"share,print and export" and when you send the email explain that it will be public for X days as a test. Then make it private after X days.

Comment: Method from +Daniel LeCheminant is better