# How to Set up multiple users at once in Trello

Tags: trello

I want to setup an office(s) up to start leveraging Trello.

My single biggest issue with this is in order to get up and running with a few good example boards I need to setup accounts for large groups of users and add pictures info etc ... (Very Time Consuming !!!)  It would be great if I could take say a spreadsheet exported from active directory and import it into Trello to get the ball rolling.

Is this possible or going to be possible, or does this all have to be done manually ??

Answer (score 2):

Put names in add members as comma seperated string. It will ask you to "click to invite" but just press ENTER instead. I tested it and it worked with three email addresses. This doesn't handle contact details/photos but it is a start. They should add this capability. Possible [dup](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19343/is-there-a-way-to-bulk-import-email-addresses-into-a-trello-account/28779#28779)